# jquery easy confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, confirmation

Anyone know how to make the confirmation dialog appear when i click on the radio buttons.
Downloaded the code from http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/. just bit confused to tweak it.

Below code will trigger the confirmation dialogue before radio button is clicked! if i use the default windows dialogue, it works fine (radio is clicked then pop up)? any solution please!

```
**HTML:**
    <input class="8" id="block_t" name="t_products" onclick="goingnow(this)" type="radio" value="Block x10 (3mins)" rel="3">Block x10 (3mins)
    <input class="9" id="block_t" name="t_products" onclick="goingnow(this)" type="radio" value="Block x10 (3mins)" rel="4">Block x10 (6mins)


**javaScript function:**
function goingnow(_this){
if ($("#going_now").attr("value") == 1) {
    $("#going_now").attr("value", 0);
} else {
    if ($(_this).is(":checked") == true) {

    var conf = $(_this).is(":checked").easyconfirm({locale: { title: 'Select Yes or No', button: ['No','Yes']}});
    if (conf){
        $("#going_now").attr("value",1);
        $("#block_mins").attr("value", $(_this).attr("rel"));
    } else {
        $("#block_mins").attr("value", $(_this).attr("rel"));
    }
}
}   
}
```

Comment: Needs less attempted blocking and more event drivenness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery Ui dialog to set a confirmation when radio is clicked on. You don't need to use any plugin for this.

```
var x = "Are you sure you want to take this action";
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('<div>' + x + '</div>').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                alert('action taken') // do something here
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close"); //close confirmation
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jZ52e/2/

Answer (score 0):

i have made a plugin that suites your needs. and even more. 
I have seen developers facing problems, and this plugin has solved all problems,

Supports: Ajax content loading, Dynamic screen centering on content change, Auto closing of dialogs (runs on timer), Powerpacked with many features.

***and its easy to use !***

```
 $.alert({
     title: 'Its easy to use',
     content: 'This is the content', // your content !
     content: 'url:form.html', // URL: prefix Loads content from the url (alternatively)
     confirm: function(){
         alert('The user clicked OK');
     }
     cancel: function(){
         alert('The user clicked cancel');
     }
 });
```

Working example and full list of features http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/